# Replace and Save Connection String in app.config but ignore database name with " Underscore "

Tags: c#, entity-framework, app-config

I want to dynamically change the connection string in app.config, and I'm having trouble whenever I use underscore in naming my database (e.g Initial Catalog=NOAH_DB ) and testing connection fail.

here is the connection string:

```
connectionString="metadata=res://*/NoahModel.csdl|res://*/NoahModel.ssdl|res://*/NoahModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=NOAHSERVER;Initial Catalog=NOAH_DB;User ID=**;Password=******;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
```

This is my current approach in changing the datasource , initial catalog , user id and password without changing or affecting the metadata

> (curently using Entity framework)

```
 config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings[key].ConnectionString = config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings[key].ConnectionString.Replace(olddatabase, newdatabase);
        config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings[key].ProviderName = "System.Data.EntityClient";
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified, true);
```

[edited]

After Building and saving the connection string, I go check the
( NOAHSystem.exe.Config ) in the bin/debug  for changes, and I observe that when saving a database name without underscore it accepts it, but lately when I tried saving w/ underscore ( e.g noah_db ) it skip and saving instead the next param without underscore

before saving

```
 connection string=&quot;data source=noahserevr;initial catalog=noah_live;user id=sa;password=@123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
```

after saving

```
connection string=&quot;data source=noahserevr;initial catalog=sa; user id=sa;password=@123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
```

Comment: *I'm having trouble*. If only there was a way to know what that trouble was.

Comment: I guess the trouble is in the error message

Comment: when I try saving the database name with underscore ( noah_db )  , instead of saving the database name , it skipped and save the user id